# Unable to reconnect to mysql database using gem mysql2

Tags: mysql, ruby, rvm, bundler

Im using gem mysql2 to connect to a MySQL database in my ruby code. In my Gemfile i have `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.11'`.But the reconnect method does not work. It says `undefined method reconnect for #<Mysql2::Client:0x8e8da0c> (NoMethodError)`.So when the mysql server goes down, inspite of me having a loop which waits for some time and then tries to reconnect, the application crashes with the above error. Why does the reconnect method not work ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it using the :reconnect flag to Mysql2::Client.new as shown  at https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#connection-options. reconnect method is not required and doesnt exist.

Answer (score 0):

try this, write in your gem file

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

then, bundle install.